# Connection pooled Spring rest template - latency issue

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using Spring rest template with connection pooling. My application has to support high load. I found the following definitions in stackoverflow as I learned that the basic RestTemplate does not support pooling.

This is my implementation:

```
@Bean
public static RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connManager.setMaxTotal(1500);
    connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(1500);

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connManager)
            .setMaxConnTotal(1500)
            .setMaxConnPerRoute(1500)
            .build();

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(3000);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(3000);
    requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(3000);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Now, only on high load, I am getting every once in a while high latency (almost 2 seconds). I am using Vert.x so I can see exactly where I am getting delayed:

```
    018-06-04 04:08:48,299 WARN  io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker - Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 1872 ms, time limit is 100
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
```

I don't believe increasing the number of the pool should do anything, 1500 is a lot (maybe even too much).

Can anyone help?
Regards, Ido

Comment: Help please. I haven't manage to fix it

Comment: you're mixing asynchronous programming (vertx) with blocking call api (resttemplate). you should not block the event loop